# How to use es6 functions params inside it?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use es6 function params in this case ?

```
 func = param => this.transform(this.targets.param)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a problem with closures; that is that the "this" does not reference what you would expect ...

Can you try the following:

```js
func = (param, that) => {
     return that.transform(param);
 }
```

Then call the function with the right context:

```js
func(param, this);
```

Comment: Great! Was it really this hard for someone to understand what i was asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. These are just normal functions.
The `parameters` of the functions are available in the scope of the function definition.

```
 func = param => this.transform(param)
```

equivalent to

```
func = param => {
     return this.transform(param);
 }
```

Comment: yes but i want to transform(this.targets.param) emphesizing THIS.TARGETS

Comment: @FilipFrank Can you please elaborate.